# How do you call an onClick event from a MenuItem in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

How do you call an `onclick` event from `MenuItem` since there is no `OnClick` property for `MenuItem` in ASP.NET?

Using `NavigateUrl` we can navaigate to a particular url but once I click on `MenuItem` it should trigger an event.

Comment: @akhil: Does it have answer for the question

Comment: Don't understand why this question has a downvote total of -2, it seems perfectly valid to me.

Comment: 15 seconds of google, less time that it took you to post the question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menuitemclick.aspx

Comment: @jbabey: I have gone through the same link before posting the question and I have tried it out but it's not working. I need for MenuItem and not for Menu

Comment: @Viswa if you read the documentation you'd see that you get which menu item was clicked through the one generic event. what you are asking for does not (and should not) exist, as it is a subset of the functionality that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Menu has `MenuItem.MenuItemClick` event, you can use that to do whatever you wanted with `onclick`.

Comment: No it doesn't have OnSelectedIndexChanged

Comment: Not in Menu, I need for MenuItem

Comment: Does the same work, you can get which item was clicked and proceed forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Menu.MenuItemClick` event of the Menu that contains your menu item:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menuitemclick.aspx

```
<asp:Menu runat="server" ID="MyMenu" onmenuitemclick="MyMenu_MenuItemClick" ... >
    ...
</asp:Menu>
```

Clicking on any menu item that does not have the `NavigateUrl` property set will cause the page to be postback and the `Menu.MenuItemClick` event handler to be executed.

Comment: Need for MenuItem and not for Menu

Comment: @Viswa - why?  The `Item` property of the `MenuEventArgs` passed to the `MenuItemClick` event handler will tell you which item was clicked.

Comment: @Viswa, the blank page sounds like an unrelated problem.  Get your debugger out.

Comment: Thanks. Made a small mistake.