# call a function in c# from menu control in html

Tags: asp.net

I have a menu control in my `aspx` file like this

```
        <div><ul>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="res_home.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="res_profile.aspx">Profile</a></li>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="res_add_profile.aspx">Add profile</a></li>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="res_category.aspx">Category</a></li>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="res_employers.aspx">Employers</a></li>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="res_login.aspx">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

how can I call a function defined in `.cs` file while pressing `logout main` item.
actually I want to clear all session variables to prevent user to go back to pages after
pressing `logout menu` item..
the `.cs` file contain the function as

```
 protected void fun(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("res_login.aspx");
}
```

I'm using `visual studio 2008` and `Mozilla` as browser.

Comment: maybe this post will help you
[Menu Item ASP event][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396321/how-do-you-call-an-onclick-event-from-a-menuitem-in-asp-net

Comment: Just make it a Server Control instead of Generic Html (meaning that put a runat="server") and do a post back to any method you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate page Logout.aspx and point the link of the logout menu item to that one.

You can then use your code in the `Page_Load` handler of the Logout.aspx to abandon the session and redirect to the login page.

Comment: but is there any other idea for this problem thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is two way to do your task.

**1  Take Asp Link button and On click link button do Server side coding to logout.**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogout" runat="server" OnClick="lnkLogout_Click"></asp:LinkButton>

protected void lnkLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Work
}
```

**2  Do your task with the help of Jquery and Ajax Call.**

```
$('#btnLogout').live("click", function () {
    CallAjaxLogout();
    window.location.href = window.referer = "LogOut.aspx";
});

function callAjaxGetJoiningDate(hashVal) {
var address = "Logout.aspx";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: address,
    data: { empCode: "em01"},
    beforeSend: function () {
        // this is where we append a loading image
        $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // successful request; do something with the data
        $('#ajax-panel').empty();


    },
    error: function () {
        // failed request; give feedback to user
        $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
    }
});
```

}

And write .CS code on Logout page load event.

```
 if (Request.Form["empCode"] != null)
            {
               Session.Abandon();
               Session.Clear();
               Response.Output.Write("Password Change");
               Response.Flush();
               Response.End();
            }
```

Hope It Helps you.

Comment: If the solution to your problem is more complicated than the problem you're trying to solve, you're probably doing something wrong.